# Add incremental number based on conditions in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column that contains text values and a column that contains dates. I am trying to add an incremental number in the third column based on first finding duplicates in the first column and then checking the date in the second column.

This is what I am after:

```
Apple   1-Jan   1
Apple   2-Jan   2
Apple   3-Jan   3
Apple   3-Jan   4
Pear    5-Mar   1
Pear    6-Mar   2
Pear    7-Mar   3
```

Since Apple is duplicated 4 times, the third column contains 1 - 4 based on the date from old to new.

Comment: How does the date come into play?  In your example it seems superfluous (no bearing on the third column).

Comment: Logically speaking, if column A contains a value that has been duplicated, count the number of times it is duplicated, then compare the dates in column B (corresponding with the duplicated values from column A), then add an incremental number in column C starting at 1, but not exceeding the total number of times that the value has been duplicated.

Comment: I'm still missing how the dates affect anything.  It seems like you would have exactly the same result if you left that column out.

Comment: Perhaps a real example will help. I have 4 documents, all with the same file name, however, each represents an incremental version. The document with the oldest date is the original document, therefore it should be version 1. The document with the newest date should be version 4.

Comment: Perhaps you are correct and I'm over complicating it. If I first sort the first column, the dates don't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Without the complication of the date, this becomes pretty straightforward.  Let's say your columns are A, B, and C.  The formula needs to compare a row to the previous row, so leave row 1 blank (so it exists but doesn't contain a value that will cause a testing problem), and start the data in row 2.  Cell C2 would contain:

```
=IF(A2=A1,C1+1,1)
```

Copy that down as needed.  If just compares the A value to the previous row.  If it is the same, it increments the count.  Otherwise it restarts the count at 1.

Comment: It's a good alternative of Countif, perfect 10 ☺

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @fixer1234 for helping me to understand that I was overcomplicating the problem.

The simple fix is to use =COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)

Comment: As usual but good one,, perfect 10 ☺